# Display resolution stuck at 640x480 about install

Tags: nvidia, display, display-resolution, gpu, gpu-driver

So I installed the latest xubuntu lts on my pc but after a reboot or two the resolution suddenly became changed and stuck to 640x480, I had already installed the proper nvidia drivers as the nouveau would cause it to freeze, any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will edit the file `/etc/default/grub` file

Step 1- Press  <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to open `terminal`

Step 2- Enter the command

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

Step 3- change the contents from

```
# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console
```

to

```
# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
GRUB_TERMINAL=console
```

Step 4- Enable the services by running

```
sudo update-grub
```

Step 5- Finally, reboot the computer.

Comment: So what effect will this have? From first glance it looks like it'll disable the gui

Comment: Take a look http://www.l3jane.net/doc/grub2/Simple-configuration.html

Comment: got me 1024x768 from 640x480 but no other options... better than nothing.

Comment: all of this is well and good but why not this... under the same instructions change the #GRUB_GFXMODE=(CHANGE TO 1024X768) or whichever resolution you need there ?